# Why do images rendered with image_style_url disappear on iPhone?

Tags: 7, media

I use "image_style_url" to render images in node template. Everything works fine on web browsers. However, these images disappear on iPhone.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="porDetCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-content">
        <?php
            foreach($node->field_project_pics[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $project_pics){
        ?>
                <img class="carousel-item" src="<?php print image_style_url('eve_project_page_detail__700x476_', $project_pics['uri']);?>" alt="">  
        <?php   
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link: http://tvphong.x10host.com/node/62

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with jcarousel. The images are rendered fine, but width and height is set to 0 on mobile.

You should be able to set widht and height in CSS.

See possible solution here: https://www.drupal.org/node/576016#comment-6041834

Attached is iphone rendering:

[image: iphone redering]